# How to register type library file (.tlb) with InstallShield LE in Visual Studio 2012 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, com-interop, installshield, typelib

I've been creating various plugins for an application that requires me to produce a .tlb file. In the past, it has simply been a case of configuring my project's build properties to 'Register for COM interop' thereby producing a .tlb file along with my output dll.  Previously, when using the Visual Studio 2010 installer projects template, this would always correctly register .tlb during installation on the target machine.

I've recently attempted to make the switch to Visual Studio 2012 and use the InstallShield LE project to produce my installer, but it doesn't seem to register the type library during the install, nor does the express addition seem to allow me to manually register via the cmd-line regasm route - or at least it's not that obvious to me.

In the InstallShield project options I had to manually add the .tlb application file (from the  build's \release folder) to the list of files to be included in the installer as it doesn't seem to get included along with the files produced by the project output or content options.  In the .tlb file's 'COM & .Net Settings' properties, I have it configured to Registration Type: 'Extract COM Information' and have enabled 'COM Interop'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this thread for a good technical description: [Are *.tlb files ever used at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245692/are-tlb-files-ever-used-at-runtime)**

In most cases I believe the *.tlb file is not needed because it is already compiled into most binaries regardless of whether it is an exe file or a dll, but .NET Interop is a lot more complex and as the other thread explains the *.tlb file can be needed to deal with advanced communication issues between threads and processes - something that I incidentially had forgotten.

When implementing a setup I have never had the need to register a *.tlb file by itself, it has been enough to register the corresponding binary (exe/dll), but this all depends on the use cases for the product.

Be aware that the way **Installshield** is registering for **COM Interop** is not always the best option as far as I recall. I am not sure exactly what they are doing, but I would check and compare with a normal **regasm.exe** registration:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx . And read the linked thread ([Are *.tlb files ever used at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245692/are-tlb-files-ever-used-at-runtime)) carefully on the issues of proxies, stubs and marshalling in case you need these features supported.

Here are some further links with concise information on **COM/DCOM**:

**Contents of a Type Library:**
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221355(v=vs.85).aspx

**COM, DCOM, and Type Libraries:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366757(v=vs.85).aspx

**Files Generated for a COM Interface:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366830(v=vs.85).aspx