# Different methods of registering .NET assemblies for COM interop and VB6

Tags: c#, com, vb6, interop

I am curious about why registering my COM interop assembly shows different results on 2 machines - using different methods of registration. I believe they are both registered the same, but they are different in the way VB6 sees them as references.

So I have a VS2013 project that is set up for COM interop. All the settings required to make COM interop work are in place.

On machine 1, I had the source code and VS2013 and VB6, so the compiler used the "Register for COM Interop" setting when it built the assembly, and in VB6 my assembly immediately appeared in the "References" list. I was able to successfully use it from VB6.

In this case I have to Dim the variable as "MyNameSpace.MyClassName".

On machine 2 I had the compiled assembly (and TLB file) and VB6. No VS2013. I used regasm /codebase to register the DLL, verified it was in the registry, yet when I opened VB6, my assembly is not in the References list. If I click "Browse" and find my assembly, it says it cannot add it. So, I browse to find the corresponding TLB file and add that to the References, and then I am able to use it.

In this case I have to Dim the variable as "MyClassName".

My question is, why are they different? Why does my assembly always just appear in the References list on the first machine, while on the second one its not listed? What does VS2013 do differently when registering my assembly for COM interop?

I am simply trying to understand this instead of fumbling about and guessing what will work. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Because you did not do the same thing you did on your dev machine.  You must use Regasm.exe /codebase /tlb.  Adding the /tlb option ensures that the type library gets registered as well so the VB6 IDE can see it.

Comment: Thanks! So the /tlb option for regasm is only needed for the VB dev environment to see the methods and properties available? Because I do not believe we currently use /tlb when registering these files during product installation, and everything works.

Comment: Correct.  There are two obscure corner-cases where the type library might be needed at runtime.  You are pretty unlikely to hit them when you use VB6.  Details [are here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14246694/17034).